# Using [mat-dialog-close] directive in a dialog component in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I used the recommended code in the dialog template to open a dialog component to confirm or cancel an action, but I faced an error with following massage, why?

```
Property mat-dialog-close is not provided by any applicable directives nor by button element
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please make sure you have imported the Material library into your module.

Comment: Please, post your code in stackblitz :)

Comment: How about just binding (click) on the button to your DialogRef? (click)="ref.close()"

Answer (score 0):

Add to `app.module.ts`

```
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';;

...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    MatDialogModule,
  ],
```

`import` in component

ts

```
import {Component, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material/dialog';

export interface DialogData {
  animal: string;
  name: string;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-overview-example.html',
})
export class DialogOverviewExample {

  animal: string;
  name: string;

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      width: '250px',
      data: {name: this.name, animal: this.animal}
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
      this.animal = result;
    });
  }

}
@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog',
  template: `
  <h1 mat-dialog-title>Hi {{data.name}}</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Favorite Animal</mat-label>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="data.animal">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">No Thanks</button>
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="data.animal" cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>
</div>`,
})
export class DialogOverviewExampleDialog {

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData) {}

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

}
```

html

```
<ol>
  <li>
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>What's your name?</mat-label>
      <input matInput [(ngModel)]="name">
    </mat-form-field>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="openDialog()">Pick one</button>
  </li>
  <li *ngIf="animal">
    You chose: <i>{{animal}}</i>
  </li>
</ol>
```

and run server `ng serve -o`.

Comment: Thanks, but I performed all...import MatDialigModule, defining Dialog service and any code to be required...

Comment: Even, I copied example of https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview, but still I have that error!

Comment: there is two diffrent import  one in the componente where use it  `{MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material/dialog'; ... constructor(public dialog: MatDialog)` and other like in the answer. Make shore you save, stop the server and run again.

Comment: Thank, I'll do it as soon as possible and inform you the result.

Comment: Hi dear, template dialog component: <h2 mat-dialog-title>Are you sure?</h2>
<mat-dialog-content>
  Are you sure to delete?
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions align="end">
  <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Cancel</button>
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="ok" cdkFocusInitial>ok</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>

Comment: th component: import { DeleteConfirmDialogComponent} from "../delete-confirm-dialog/delete-confirm-dialog.component"; import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef} from "@angular/material/dialog"; deleteAction(): void {
    const dialogRef=this.dialog.open(DeleteConfirmDialogComponent);
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result=>{
      console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`);
    });  and app.module : import {MatDialogModule} from "@angular/material/dialog";